# Update statement based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to update column in table get it from another table and I have relation between two tables as parent have primary key "tbl_Inv_ClientItemsReturnOrders" and child have foreign key "tbl_Inv_ClientItemsReturnOrderDetails".

I try this

```
update U
set U.InventoryReturnReasonID =
        (select InventoryReturnReasonID
         from tbl_Inv_ClientItemsReturnOrders
         where ClientItemsReturnOrderID = U.ClientItemsReturnOrderID)
from [dbo].[tbl_Inv_ClientItemsReturnOrderDetails] U
```

But I get this error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.The statement has been terminated.

I want to update column "InventoryReturnReasonID" in table "tbl_Inv_ClientItemsReturnOrderDetails"  by value of column  "InventoryReturnReasonID" from table "tbl_Inv_ClientItemsReturnOrders"

Comment: So what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @TimSchmelter i edit the question

Comment: This is because in tbl_Inv_ClientItemsReturnOrders there are more than one records against a ClientItemsReturnOrderID, and that is why subquery is returning more than one rows. Check the logic of your query and involve more filters in where clause to return only one row, may be a line item is also involved in return order which you are missing in filter.

Comment: @Niraj yes i have this case my detail table have more than one row have the same header id but i have no more filter i need

Comment: Then use top 1 InventoryReturnReasonID in subquery to get single row item as suggested by Gordon.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the query given below for getting better idea about the issue.

```
 SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tbl_Inv_ClientItemsReturnOrderDetails] U
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Inv_ClientItemsReturnOrders] P ON (P.ClientItemsReturnOrderID = U.ClientItemsReturnOrderID)
```

we have the option to compile update with join. The query is as follows

```
 UPDATE U
 SET U.InventoryReturnReasonID = P.InventoryReturnReasonID
 FROM [dbo].[tbl_Inv_ClientItemsReturnOrderDetails] U
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Inv_ClientItemsReturnOrders] P ON (P.ClientItemsReturnOrderID = U.ClientItemsReturnOrderID)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear.  You can select an *arbitrary* value using `TOP 1`:

```
Update U
  set U.InventoryReturnReasonID = (select TOP 1 ro.InventoryReturnReasonID
                                   from tbl_Inv_ClientItemsReturnOrders ro
                                   where ro.ClientItemsReturnOrderID = U.ClientItemsReturnOrderID
                                  )
  from [dbo].tbl_Inv_ClientItemsReturnOrderDetails U;
```

Normally, `TOP` should have an `ORDRER BY`.  You can include an `ORDER BY` to specify which of multiple values the update should use.

Note:  Using qualified column names (i.e. including a table alias) is always a good idea.  It should be mandatory with a correlated subquery because of the potential danger if something goes wrong.  For instance, your query would return too many rows if the column `ro.ClientItemsReturnOrderID` did not exist.

Another approach is to use aggregation:

```
Update U
  set U.InventoryReturnReasonID = (select max(ro.InventoryReturnReasonID)
                                   from tbl_Inv_ClientItemsReturnOrders ro
                                   where ro.ClientItemsReturnOrderID = U.ClientItemsReturnOrderID
                                  )
  from [dbo].tbl_Inv_ClientItemsReturnOrderDetails U;
```

Comment: @Radwa . . . You cannot get that error if you use `TOP 1`.  You might get another error, but not that particular error . . . Hmmm, unless you are using MS Access where `TOP 1` really means `TOP 1 WITH TIES`.